# Strange behaviour when adding event-functions from inside functions and passing elements

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Today I came across a strange behaviour in JavaScript when I was adding a function to an `onclick` event.

Let me explain:
When dynamically creating some buttons and adding a function to their `onclick` events, like this:

```
function createButton(a) {
    button = document.createElement("button");
        button.setAttribute("id","a"+a);
        button.innerHTML = "a"+a;
        button.onclick = function () {
            alert("Should be the same: a"+a+" and "+this.id);
        };
    return button;
}

for (var a=0;&lt;3=;a++) {
    document.body.appendChild(createButton(a));
}
```

I get this message when pressing the first button:

> "Should be the same: a0 and a0"*, as expected.

But when I want to do the same thing without using a separate function (`createButton`) like this:

```
var button;
for (var a=0;a&lt;=3;a++) {
    button = document.createElement("button");
    button.setAttribute("id","a"+a);
    button.innerHTML = "a"+a;
    button.onclick = function () {
        alert("Should be the same: a"+a+" and "+this.id);
    };
    document.body.appendChild(button);
}
a=999;
```

Now I got this message when pressing the first button:

> "Should be the same: a999 and a0"*.

Does anyone know why they doesn't produce the same alerts? And is there any way of making the second example work like the first one? (i know that
`button.onclick = "alert('Should be the same: a"+a+" and "+this.id+"'))` does the trick, but that's just ugly)

Any help would be appreciated, the script may be viewed at http://xc-results.com/static/stackoverflowq1.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second example, `button.onclick` is a closure: a function + some bounded variables (in this case, `a`). That means that `a` will be evaluated at the moment `onclick()` is *evaluated*, not at the moment it is *defined*. At the moment `button.onclick` is ran, `a` equals 999, hence your result.

Comment: Okay, so in the first example a is "evaluated" at the point when the function is defined?

Comment: Not exactly, I was unclear. In both cases, a is evaluated at the moment the button is pressed. The difference is this: in the first case, each time the for loop iterates, it creates a new `a` (equaling 0, 1, 2 and 3). Those 4 `a`s will live while the script is running, and each `onclick()` method will respectively refer to them. In the second example, the `a` the `onclick()` method refers to is the global `a`, the one that later gets set to 999.

Comment: ah, that explains it! I guess there's no way of creating different a:s using the function () {};-way then.. Ah well, I guess I'll have to stick to the first example then. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common problem .

a in the alert is a reference to the variable a which takes value 999 . So all alert will have  same a = 999.

To avoid this you need to evaluate a immediately while adding onclick .

```
    var b = a;
    button.onclick = function () {
        alert("Should be the same: a"+b+" and "+this.id);
    };
```

This would most probably work .

Comment: Note this will work only when `a` is a number. Otherwise `a` is passed by reference and will be changed. You'll need a closure to fix that.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I've tried that as well, unfortunately it produces the same result.

Comment: Whops, my mistake, when doing this way I get *Should be the same: a3 and a0*, where "a0" corresponds to "var b=a" (==3) at the end of the loop.

Comment: @ Radagaisus -- nice point . But doesnt var b = a call copy constructor like in c++ ? this will lead to deep copy . Not sure though .

Answer (score 0):

That's not a strange behavior in JavaScript.

You are calling `alert()` after the script finished its evaluation and `a` is equal to `999`. Think about it.